# Add a span inside a div with dangerouslySetInnerHTML for showing a tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tooltip

There is a div element which has a link to a page set like this:

```
  <a href={row.original.productURL}>
    <div className="product-sku">
      <p>{row.values.sku}</p>
      <div
        className="product-details"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: row.original.description
        }}>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

it works fine but I want to add a tooltip to it when hover, so I tried to add a span inside the div:

```
  <a href={row.original.productURL}>
    <div className="product-sku">
      <p>{row.values.sku}</p>
      <div
        className="tooltip product-details"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: row.original.description
        }}>
        <span className="tooltiptext">This is my tooltip</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

It seems to be forbidden as it returns an error:

**Uncaught Error: Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.**

Is there a way to add a tooltip in this case?

Comment: The problem is that React will set the innerHTML to the object you have given - it can't cope with your having put some stuff in there as well. Would putting the tooltip in a pseudo element be possible as it wouldn't interfere with the document structure that React is creating for you.

Comment: I don't understand... can you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for what you asked, however if someone else is having this issue... you just have to simply append your HTML to the __html prop.

Basically this:

```
<div
    className="tooltip product-details"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: row.original.description
    }}>
    <span className="tooltiptext">This is my tooltip</span>
</div>
```

becomes this:

```
<div
    className="tooltip product-details"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: row.original.description + `<span class="tooltiptext">This is my tooltip</span>`
    }}>
</div>
```

This allows you to nest div/span classes within a div which uses the dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop.